# Difference between websocket and vertx

Tags: websocket, vert.x

I've been recently learning about vertx and websocket.
What I understood that you can have real-time application using them, but I didn't understand the difference between them
A websocket lets you push messages from server to client and vice-versa, encouraging the publish-subscribe methodology. Then what is vertx doing? It acts as an event bus and also encourages publish-subscribe model.

I can be completely wrong in my analysis, hence please correct me and I'll be glad. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets is a stateful protocol, usually used to communicate between clients and servers.

Vert.x is a server-side framework, which has a very good support for WebSockets.

You don't have to use WebSockets with Vert.x. But if you do want to use WebSockets, Vert.x is a great option.

Here's an article I wrote a few months ago about both:

https://medium.com/@alexey.soshin/playing-ping-pong-over-websockets-with-vert-x-447c634c6c87

Comment: Thanks Alexey, what I understood about Websocket is that Websocket makes use of destination/end-points to publish/subscribe messages.
So when we use websocket with vertx, does Vertx publish the message to the websocket destination?

Comment: It seems like there's still some misunderstanding. Vert.x server is the WebSocket endpoint. Your WebSocket client can connect to a WebSocket server, which can be implemented using Vert.x

Comment: Regarding _"Vert.x is a server-side framework"_, it's worth noting that [the Vert.x documentation explicitly states](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/): "_**Vert.x is not a framework but a toolkit**: the core library defines the fundamental APIs for writing asynchronous networked applications, and then you can pick the useful modules for your application_" and "_Eclipse **Vert.x is a toolkit** for building reactive applications on the JVM_". There's no Vert.x "framework" guiding/constraining a developer in the way that other popular frameworks like Spring or Hibernate or JSF might do.